# Do Play evolutions work with Slick (or just with play-slick)

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, playframework-evolutions

We've run into a bunch of [problems](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/345) using `play-slick` so I've reverted to a straight-up Slick 3.1.1 implementation.

This fixed our various problems with concurrency but... now I'm trying to add evolutions, and it doesn't seem to be working. I've added the following to `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1", ...`

And, when I did I noticed the "play-slick-evolutions" and thought, "Oh no, I bet those only with with `play-slick`." Seems to be the case, because the evolutions are *not* firing.

When I try to turn them on I get the following exceptions:

```
[error]   ! work from within a browser
[error]    com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
[error]
[error]    1) No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound.
[error]      while locating play.api.db.DBApi
[error]        for parameter 3 at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:45)
[error]      at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:22):
[error]    Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
[error]
[error]    2) No implementation for play.api.db.DBApi was bound.
[error]      while locating play.api.db.DBApi
[error]        for parameter 0 at play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi.<init>(EvolutionsApi.scala:71)
[error]      at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:21):
[error]    Binding(interface play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
[error]
[error]    2 errors (Errors.java:466)
[error] com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
[error] com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
[error] com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
[error] com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
[error] com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
[error] com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
[error] play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
[error] play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
[error] play.api.test.FakeApplication.<init>(Fakes.scala:216)
[error] play.api.test.WithBrowser$.$lessinit$greater$default$2(Specs.scala:74)
[error] application.TestBrowserResponses$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon$1.<init>(TestBrowserResponses.scala:8)
[error] application.TestBrowserResponses$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestBrowserResponses.scala:8)
[error] application.TestBrowserResponses$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestBrowserResponses.scala:8)
```

Anyone know if it's possible to use evolutions with just plain Slick?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem as I am experiencing this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Evolutions` can be used with plain `Slick` without using `play-slick`.

You can add dependencies with

```
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

Also, make sure `play.evolutions.enabled` is not set to `false` in `application.conf` to trigger evolutions.

> Evolutions are automatically activated if a database is configured in
>   application.conf and evolution scripts are present.

Please refer to [Evolutions documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Evolutions) for more details.

**Update:**
Regarding the exception you are getting. Refer to this documentation. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured

Comment: Whenever I try to activate evolutions, I'm getting a lengthy exception about the DB API driver not being loaded. I've annotated my original question with more detail.

Comment: @Zac Check out: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured

Comment: yea, read it a few times... but that's not the source of the problem. We are not using JDBC directly, are not adding it into our build, and our database init code looks like `val driver = PostgresDriver; val db = Database.forConfig("trident.db")` so... Ya. It's just not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add your sql app specific jdbc driver to `build.sbt`, because slick comes without it. For example:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.8.11.2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)
```